Integrating an HTML form with Google Apps script, but unable to upload a picture
I've built a form in HTML, and it's largely submitting properly into Google Apps Script. It's inputting information into a Google Sheet, creating a custom Folder based on the person submitting the form, creating a PDF based on the person's submission, and uploading that into the respective person's folder.
I'm also trying to get the form to upload a picture as well. I'm not wanting to rewrite my entire form/code just to add this uploading picture functionality, and based on what I can see, it shouldn't be too complicated. The blob seems to be added to the form submission, and I've tried half-a-dozen different ways to retrieve the blob in Apps Script, but nothing seems to be actually downloading the file into Google Drive.
I should note that I'm not building my HTML in Apps Script in the Index.html file. I'd rather embed my html separately into my webpage, and then recall the Apps Script code with the fetch API. Although, my code is pretty much a conglomeration of google results, ChatGPT, and Google Gemini... So I'm open to advice/suggestions
My HTML form is pretty straight-forward, so I'll just enclose the relevant JS and Apps Script code below:
<script>
     window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          const form = document.getElemntById('TestForm');
          form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

               const data = newFormData(form);

               const action = e.target.action;
               fetch(action, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data
               })
               .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                         throw new Error('HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}');
                    }
                    return response.text();
               .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error during form submission:', error);
               });
          })
     })
</script>

function doPost(e) {
     try {
          const pictureFolderId = "PICTURE-FOLDER-ID";
          const pictureFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pictureFolderId)
          uploadImage(e, pictureFolder)
     } catch (error) {
          //Logging errors and such
     }
}

function uploadImage(e, pictureFolder) {
     const file = e.parameters.file[0];
     const imageBlob = file.getAs(MimeType.PNG)

     pictureFolder.createFile(imageBlob);
}

This last function, uploadImage(), is what I think the issue revolves around. I've tried different ways of retrieving the blob, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've also tried using Utilities.newblob(file.getByes()), but that didn't work. I also tried to use e.getBlob(), though that didn't seem to work. It seems like it should be simple, but evidently it's not. At least for me. Can someone help me out, and/or explain why what I'm trying isn't working?
EDIT [I've added my HTML]:
<body>
     <form
          method="post"
          action="INSERT-GOOGLE-URL-HERE"
          id="TestForm"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <input type="text" name="FirstName">
          <input type="text" name="LastName">

          <label for="imageUpload">Please upload a photo of yourself:</label>
          <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="imageUpload" accept="image/*">

          <button type="submit">Send</button>
     </form>
</body>


Use DriveApp ornthe Drive Advanced Services to grab the folder on the server side code

About I'm also trying to get the form to upload a picture as well., in order to confirm this, can you provide your HTML?

Wow, it amazes me how fast people respond here on StackOverFlow! Thanks so much for the quick responses! I edited the post to also include the HTML

The following code works for me:
code.gs
function doPost(e) {
...
  uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e, dropbox);
}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e, dropbox) {
  var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
  }

  var data = e.parameter.fileContent;
  var filename = e.parameter.filename;
  var contentType = data.substring(5, data.indexOf(';')),
    bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,') + 7)),
    blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, filename);
  var file = folder.createFile(blob);
  return file.getId();
}

UploadFile.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="uploadForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzCss...Vh_29m/exec" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="filesize" id="filesize">
      <input type="hidden" value="" name="filetype" id="filetype">
      
      <label> Name: </label><input required type="text" value="" name="name" id="name">  
      <label> Email: </label><input required type="text" value="" name="email" id="email">
      <label> Contact: </label><input required type="text" value="" name="contact" id="contact">  


      </form>
      <input required id="attach" name="attach" type="file"/>
      <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" />
      
      <script>
      function UploadFile() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
      var fName = file.name;
      var fSize = file.size;
      var fType = file.type;
      console.log("fName = " + fName);
      console.log("fSize = " + fSize);
      console.log("fType = " + fType);
      
      reader.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('fileContent').value=reader.result;
      document.getElementById('filename').value=file.name;
      document.getElementById('filetype').value=file.type;
      document.getElementById('filesize').value=file.size;
      document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
      </script>

  </body>
</html>


Hm, I tried changing my code to match, but it didn't work... Was there something that you did in your HTML/JavaScript to create the parameters for fileContent & filename?

Yes. I'm using FileReader(). I have added the html file code to my answer. There's some extra stuff in there for you, since I'm using some data to send myself an email about a file upload.

That worked! thank you so much! I had things structured a little different, but just used onchange() on the file input to trigger the function
